# Update EF model - DB at different location

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I am very new to **EF programming**.

My application gets the data from existing database. (**DB first**)

Now I have come to situation where I want to update my model to newer DB. basically the core schema is same as previous but has some modification in the table.

When I change the DB name for **app.config** and  update the model it gives list of error

have I missed something?

Comment: What errors does it gives?

Comment: Once I update and when re-build the project it shows some errors saying fields are not mapped

Comment: Was the new db created using code first too?

Comment: no. Db was already there.

Comment: So, it's not code first, right?

Comment: @ivowiblo- yes. it is not code first

Answer (score 1):

When you do an update it merges the model you have with the DB that you update from. Additional columns are added to your existing entities but columns that you have removed from the DB are not removed from your entities and you need to remove these mappings yourself.

If you know which tables have columns removed it sometimes easier to delete the entity from your model and then do an update to reload it from the DB.

If you've don't know what tables or there have been many then it may be easier to delete all entities from your model and just do a full Update to reload the the new DB structure.